# WordPress replace page with a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a plugin that will display custom page when a parameter is present in the URL. For example, let's say that the URL of a post is  `localhost/wp/2018/03/22/postname/`, it displays post normally as expected. What I want to achieve, is when I specify URL as `localhost/wp/2018/03/22/postname/?param=1`, I want to display page that I will generate with the plugin. I made a function that works when the parameter is present and it echoes some example content, however, it merges with what WordPress normally displays. So when I put the parameter into URL I get a regular page with post and my content somewhere in the middle. I want to display only the page that i generate from scratch, from `<html>` to `</html>` with my plugin. How can I do that?

Comment: i can think of using php `include(filename)` based on the parameter in the starting of the file. But not with plugin :S

Comment: We need to "erase" the default WordPress output and display our. It's like changing theme, but only for the viewer. So i guess it won't help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a filter in WordPress called `template_include` this filter is executed before any output is displayed on the WordPress generated page.

You can override the current template via this filter as soon as you find the parameter and value in the URL. E.g. below is a filter I was using in a project to override archive & single template for a certain CPT:

```
function em_templates($template) {
  if(get_query_var('post_type')  == 'xyz'  ) {

          return FMM__DIR__ . '/templates/archive-xyz.php';
   }

    return $template;
}


add_filter('template_include', 'em_templates', 1, 1);
```

You can adopt this logic for parameter and use this WordPress filter to take over the template process and display yours own.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! I can't vote yet but thank you very much :D

Comment: @Coprobo Glad to know! Happy WP Hacking :)